# How to get information about files being copied to my machine by remote rsync command?

Tags: ssh, process, rsync, remote

I am rsyncing a directory from machine **B** to machine **A**. `rsync` command is run on machine **B**.

On machine **A**, what kind of information can I get about this `rsync` process (progress/amount of data downloaded etc.) without `ssh`ing into machine **B**?

Comment: What network connection does machine B use to connect to machine A?

Comment: @Silent-Bob local lan.

Comment: I meant what protocol. rsh, ssh, ...?

Comment: @Silent-Bob `ssh`

Comment: enable verbose output to see the files being transferred, rsync -v

Comment: @Creek question is about machine A, not machine B.

Comment: @user13107 well then, iftop -b will show you, among other things, the amount of data transferred across the wire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have enough permissions, you can either `strace` the receiving `rsync` process or use `lsof` to see what files it has open.

Find the rsync process pid, eg using `pgrep rsync`, but choose the child as there will probably be two. Then use eg

```
strace -p 4484 -e rename
```

where 4484 is the found pid. It will show you each new file being created as it is renamed from the temporary name. You can simplify the output a bit with:

```
pid=$(pgrep -n rsync)
strace -p "$pid" -e rename 2>&1 | sed 's/.*", //;s/) = 0//'
```

Alternatively, use eg

```
 watch ls -l /proc/4484/fd/1
```

which seems to be the file descriptor being used to write to the temp file. 
This will show you at least the directory it is in.

Comment: The `strace` command did not work. It said `attach: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...): Operation not permitted
`

Comment: `watch ls -l` worked. It showed the file being copied currently.

Comment: The `strace` needs you to be the same user as rsync, or root, so perhaps it will work if you do `sudo strace ...`, if you can.

Answer (score 6):

You can specify an option to remote system to log eg.

```
--remote-option=--log-file=/path/to/log/rsync.log
```

this is an example from a small rsync run

```
2015/10/21 10:59:43 [10785] receiving file list
2015/10/21 10:59:43 [10785] created directory stack2
2015/10/21 10:59:43 [10785] cd+++++++++ ./
2015/10/21 10:59:43 [10785] >f+++++++++ Filexxx
2015/10/21 10:59:43 [10785] >f+++++++++ logfile
2015/10/21 10:59:43 [10785] >f+++++++++ logfile.sh
2015/10/21 10:59:43 [10785] cd+++++++++ dir1/
2015/10/21 10:59:43 [10785] >f+++++++++ dir1/FileA
2015/10/21 10:59:43 [10785] >f+++++++++ dir1/FileB
2015/10/21 10:59:43 [10785] >f+++++++++ dir1/FileC
2015/10/21 10:59:43 [10785] >f+++++++++ dir1/filec
2015/10/21 10:59:43 [10785] cd+++++++++ dir2/
2015/10/21 10:59:43 [10785] >f+++++++++ dir2/filea
2015/10/21 10:59:43 [10785] >f+++++++++ dir2/fileb
2015/10/21 10:59:43 [10785] sent 240 bytes  received 1,703 bytes  total size 1,051
```

Comment: I like this answer but I'm choosing the other as it works on an already running `rsync` command (even when remote-log option is not given).